# If stament in a class call

Tags: php, class, if-statement, operator-keyword

I am trying to put an if statement when calling a class, but the operator -> produces a problem I cant figure out. So calling the class like:

```
$email = WP_Mail::init()
      ->to('myemail@hotmail.com')
      ->subject('This is an automated message pleas do not reply')
      ->template(plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) .'email-templates/email.php', [
        'name' => 'Anthony Budd',
        'email' => 'test@test.com',
        'skills' => [
           'PHP',
           'AWS',
        ] 
    ]);
    if (site_url() === 'mysite'){
      ->send();
    }else {
      ->render();
      echo $email;
    }

normally it would look like:

$email = WP_Mail::init()
  ->to('john.doe@gmail.com')
  ->template(get_template_directory() .'/emails/demo.php', [
  'name' => 'Anthony Budd',
  'location' => 'London',
  'skills' => [
       'PHP',
       'AWS',
    ] 
])
->send();
```

this above produces an error due to the operator, how can I return "->render()" or "->send()". I want to display the data if on my dev computer but when I push the code to me server it needs to send the email.

Comment: At a guess `$email->render();`

Comment: `if (my_site === my_site){` is not valid PHP syntax. Was this real code or just pseudo code

Comment: So you want to hook into the call of `WP_Mail::init()` to then call another function (instead?) depending on a condition?

Comment: Please, copy-paste the real code, not just part of it. Otherwise, there is no way we can figure out the code around. I'm talking about this context.

Comment: Sorry, just did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the object `$email` before calling the methods. Take a look at this:

```
if (site_url() === 'mysite'){
  $email->send();
}else {
  $email->render();
  echo $email;
}
```

Comment: It is not working, new at OOP but don't I have to call them all at ones? See how it normally would work, and if I try this solution it can't return a string from "echo $email"

Comment: Maybe you want to `return $email->render();`?

Comment: Thats, it. You’r a star! Thanks